# Can -que be used with adverbs?

Tags: syntax, adverb

If I wanted to say something like "I love you now and forever", can I use `-que` with one of the adverbs like I would with nouns?

> Nunc perpetuoque te amo.

I tried searching various adverbs with `-que` attached but didn't find anything attested.

Comment: The answer to the general question in the title is, absolutely, e.g. *minimeque* Caes. BG 1,1. Whether the concrete example is idiomatic is a different question; examples like that are harder to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TKR has already demonstrated that the enclitic *-que* can be attached to adverbs. Often -- perhaps more often than not -- this is done to join sentences or clauses. Here, though, are a few examples that are structurally close to your example:

> ex multis audiebam quam **fortiter sapienterque** ferres iniuriam temporum
> *I heard from many how valiantly and how wisely you have borne the outrages of the times*

Cicero, [Ad familiares 6,10b](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fam6.shtml#10b)

> Agricola naturali prudentia, quamvis inter togatos, **facile iusteque** agebat.
> *Agricola, thanks to his natural prudence, although among civilians, acted courteously and justly.*

Tacitus, [De vita Iulii Agricolae 9.2](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0084%3Achapter%3D9%3Asection%3D2)

> Breve enim tempus aetatis satis longum est ad **bene honesteque** vivendum
> *A short lifetime is still long enough to live well and honourably*

Cicero, [Cato maior de senectute 70](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/senectute.shtml#70)

If you should change your mind and decide to say *in perpetuum* instead of *perpetuo*, then you have the option of saying *in perpetuumque*, but note that *inque* is also good classical usage.

By the way, I think this would also be a good opportunity for a double-et, i.e. *et nunc et in perpetuum*.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about double _et_. I like how that flows.

Answer (score 10):

Sure! Pretty much anything can be conjoined with -*que*. Here are some PHI searches: *[saepeque](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=saepeque), [semperque](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=semperque), [beneque](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=beneque), [maleque](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=maleque)*.

Comment: I need to improve my search game. Thanks!